# Twitter gem update_with_media method is returning "could not authenticate you"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm using the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to automate tweets. Since I want my tweets to also include an image I'm using the "update_with_media" method, like so:

```
def tweet
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "my consumer key"
      config.consumer_secret     = "my consumer secret"
      config.access_token        = "my access token"
      config.access_token_secret = "my secret access token"
    end

    client.update_with_media("Some text \n ", open(self.image_url))
  end
```

The error that the being returned by twitter states "cannot authenticate you". My credentials I'm using above are most definitely correct though, as it posts a tweet without error when I use the update method (tweet w/out an image). Does anyone have any experience dealing with this or a similar issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the full error stacktrace?

Comment: I am having the same issue, still haven't been able to fix it... Any updates @xxyyxx ?

Comment: @Breno I was able to figure it out, but I forgot how. I'll update my post with answer later tonight when I get home, or tomorrow at the latest. I unfortunately do not have the code handy right now.